Angular/ts row drag to another grid creates duplicates
I'm trying with some fake data to row drag a row to another grid. But whenever I drag a row to the other grid the row gets duplicated in the target grid.
Besides that I'm trying to check weither the column you try to drag is already present in the target grid. But also this part doesn't work like it should. (sometimes swal err, sometimes not)
draft grid = source grid
final grid = target grid
It could also be you want to drag something back from the final grid to the draft grid.
Can anyone help me understand why it is duplicating the dragged rows?





Before drag 'Slaapkamer 3':
After drag 'Slaapkamer 3':
